# How to add an argument as Character type to NSMutableArray in Swift

Tags: swift, string, nsmutablearray, character

I'm trying to add Character type to NSMutableArray, but it showed me the error: "Argument type Character does not conform to expected type AnyObject".

```
for (i, c) in (str?.characters.enumerate())! {
    //c is Character type
    if (!((uniqueLetterArray?.containsObject(c)))) { //error when check c in array
        uniqueLetterArray?.addObject(c)          //error when add c into array
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's very little reason to use `NSMutableArray` in Swift. Use Swift's native array type:

```
var uniqueLetterArray = [Character]()
for char in str.characters {
    if !uniqueLetterArray.contains(char) {
        uniqueLetterArray.append(char)
    }
}
```

Comment: @vinhsteven If you find Code Different's answer correct you should accept his / her answer.

Answer (score 0):

Character is a struct. NSArray is an array of objects, and you cannot put a struct in an array of objects.

Really, you should definitely be using Array instead, but if you insist, you could covert it into an NSString and add that instead.